# 2 arrays match data into 1 array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have 2 array's, first array have for example **ItemID** of my item, second array have description about my item. I want to match data into 1 array.

It looks like:

```
[rgInventory] => Array
    (
        [1234567890] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1234567890
                [classid] => 123456789
                [instanceid] => 987654321
                [amount] => 1
                [pos] => 1
            )
    )

[rgDescriptions] => Array
    (
        [192837465_918273645] => Array
            (
                [appid] => 730
                [name] => Something
            )
    )
```

Items in arrays don't have the same value like *ID*, but they are in the same order so:

Description for the first item in rgInventory is in the first array inside rgDescriptions.

What should I do to match for example **id** from `rgInventory` with **name** from `rgDescriptions` in the same array for example `$backpack = array();`?

Regards for you.

Comment: you can use `array_merge()`

Comment: @Drudge but `array_merge()` doesn't match first item from `rgInventory` with first item from `rgDescriptions`.

Comment: How you gonna match the first item from `rgInventory` with fist item from `rgDescription` ?? There is no any common thing .

Comment: I don't know, that is why I asked here. Maybe I can use `for();` and in order add values from `rgInventory`, after that in the same order I will add values from `rgDescriptions`? But how to do this?

Comment: Can you please show us your code that you have tried??

Comment: @Drudge I've tried this: [link](https://codeshare.io/2zEpd) but it doesn't work, it's match wrong id with name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$array1 = array('rgInventory' => 
             array(
                    '1234567890' => array(
                                    'id' => 1234567890,
                                    'classid' => 123456789,
                                    'instanceid' => 987654321,
                                    'amount' => 1,
                                    'pos' => 1
                                    )
                        )
                );

$array2 = array(
               'rgDescriptions' => array(
                     '192837465_918273645' => array(
                            'appid' => 730, 'name' => 'Something')
                                    )
               );
```

Create new function to combine the two arrays into one array:

```
function array_sum_recursive($data1, $data2) {
       if (!is_array($data1) && !is_array($data2)) {
        return $data1 + $data2;
    }
    // deepest array gets precedence
    if (!is_array($data2)) {
        return $data1;
    }
    if (!is_array($data1)) {
        return $data2;
    }
     //merge and remove duplicates
    $keys = array_unique(array_merge(array_keys($data1), array_keys($data2)));
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        if (isset($data1[$key]) && isset($data2[$key])) {
            $result[$key] = array_sum_recursive($data1[$key], $data2[$key]); 
        } else if (isset($data1[$key])) {
            $result[$key] = $data1[$key];
        } else {
            $result[$key] = $data2[$key];
        }
    }
    if(empty($result)){
        echo "no result";
        die();
    }else{
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Put the two array in one array `$newarray`:

```
$newonearray = array_sum_recursive($array1, $array2);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($newonearray);

?>
```

And you will get this:

```
Array
(
    [rgInventory] => Array
        (
            [1234567890] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1234567890
                    [classid] => 123456789
                    [instanceid] => 987654321
                    [amount] => 1
                    [pos] => 1
                )

        )

    [rgDescriptions] => Array
        (
            [192837465_918273645] => Array
                (
                    [appid] => 730
                    [name] => Something
                )

        )

)
```

Hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use function [each](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php) to get each element of both arrays, then merge its with [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and save this new item to backup array.

Try something like this

```
<?php

$rgInventory = ['firstInv' => ['invId' => 1], 'secondInv' => ['invId' => 2]];
$rgDescriptions = ['firstDesc' => ['descId' => 1], 'secondDesc' => ['descId' => 2]];

if (count($rgInventory) && count($rgInventory) == count($rgDescriptions)) {
    $backpack = [];

    while($inventory = each($rgInventory)) {
        $description = each($rgDescriptions);
        $item = array_merge($inventory['value'], $description['value']);
        $backpack[] = $item;
    }

    var_dump($backpack);
}
```

Output will be:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["invId"]=>
    int(1)
    ["descId"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["invId"]=>
    int(2)
    ["descId"]=>
    int(2)
  }
}
```